# Visual Studio: On Breakpoint, start debug in other program instance

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2017

Here's a fun one for you Visual C# debugging wizards out there:

Is it possible to set the action of a breakpoint in the debug of a C# solution to continue from a paused debug state in another visual studio solution?

So Program A hits breakpoint X, whose action instigates Program B (in another instance of the same version of visual studio) to run until the next break point or close.

EDIT --
I'm not expecting state from A to be transferred into B or something stupid.  I'm saying once B kicks off, its just normal program B execution, its as if I clicked the continue button, except it has been automated.

Comment: Of course it's possible, since you can run macros at breakpoints and extensions to listen for interprocess events from those macros.  Not sure if it's worth it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup multiple startup options in VS:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165413.aspx

Comment: Travis, interesting, I think I would like this, however, this would be a cross-solution, not a cross-project jump.  I suppose I could import the other program from the other solution, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: Apologies as I misunderstood your setup. What kind of programs are they? If they are web then you will change your config to point to your localhost:whatevr port of your other solution running in visual studio. If they are a desktop or windows service then you would open the other solution up and instead of running it, you would go to "Debug > attach to process" on the top menu. You would then select the exe of your running program. Trick is here is that you have to have the second program installed/running on your machine already in order to attach to it. Makes it kinda a pain when debugging.

Comment: Here is some good ole fun reading as I'm sure my comment was about as clear as mud: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx